# Purecomponent state does not update but props do

Tags: reactjs, redux, immutable.js

Have a react pure component that updates when the redux store changes...  All the objects are immutable... I have a immutable map as my root in store, and a map of books (in map form).  When the update fires, my props value changes to be correct but my state value does not...

I am assuming its because of shallow comparison but i wanted to ask the experts what they would do. What they think is going on....

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import _bookDetails from './_bookDetails'
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import BookForm, {PERSPECTIVE} from './BookForm'
import * as bookActions from "../../actions/bookActions";

class BookDetailsPage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
        this.state = {
            showUpdateForm: false,
            book: this.props.book,
            date: this.props.date
        };
        this.toggleUpdate = this.toggleUpdate.bind(this);
    }


    render() {
        console.log(this.state.book);
        console.log(this.props.book);
        ...

}

// Map state to props
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
    let allBooks = state.get('books');
    let book = state.get('book');
    try{
        book = allBooks.get(book.get('id'));
    } catch(err){
        console.warn('empty book object');
    }
    return {
        book: book,
        date: new Date()
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
     return {
        fetchBookById: bookId => dispatch(bookActions.fetchBookById(bookId))
    };
};

export default withRouter(
    connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(BookDetailsPage)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are only binding `this.state.book` to `this.props.book` **once** in the constructor. The constructor only gets called **one time**, when the component is first mounted. What you need is to use `componentDidUpdate` to update `this.state.book` anytime that `this.props.book` updates:

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import _bookDetails from './_bookDetails'
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import BookForm, {PERSPECTIVE} from './BookForm'
import * as bookActions from "../../actions/bookActions";

class BookDetailsPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state = {
      showUpdateForm: false,
      book: this.props.book,
      date: this.props.date
    };
    this.toggleUpdate = this.toggleUpdate.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    // Make sure your book prop is different
    if(prevProps.book !== this.props.book) {
      // Update state with new book value
      this.setState({
        book: this.props.book
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.book);
    console.log(this.props.book);
  ...

  }

// Map state to props
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
    let allBooks = state.get('books');
    let book = state.get('book');
    try{
        book = allBooks.get(book.get('id'));
    } catch(err){
        console.warn('empty book object');
    }
    return {
        book: book,
        date: new Date()
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
     return {
        fetchBookById: bookId => dispatch(bookActions.fetchBookById(bookId))
    };
};

export default withRouter(
    connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(BookDetailsPage)
);
```